# API google maps адрес Ленина 30 находит в чужом городе, если не задать явно свой, как исправить?

Tags: google-maps-api, javascript

Юзеру приходиться явно прописывать Москва Ленина 30, хочется чтоб юзер писал Ленина 30 а  API google maps поняло что подразумевается тот город в котором находится юзер, при этом его координаты уже известны.
Может в сам запрос Directions Service нужно что то добавить?

```
request = {
          origin: marker.getPosition(),
          destination: Ленина 30,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
          }

Любые Ваши соображения!
```

Comment: так надо сначала определить город юзера, это делается с помошью 
html5 geo api

[demo](http://html5demos.com/geo)

но при этом сайт как минимум один раз спросит у юзера разрешение детектить его.

Comment: Так на демо город не определяется, определяется его местоположение, а оно, как я сказал, у меня уже есть. Я не знаю что с ним делать дальше, чтоб юзер мог вписывать только улицу и дом, а API Google map понимало что искать нужно в городе юзера.

Comment: так вы у гугля спросите чего там за город по координатам, он умеет.